# Doesn't Xul'l browser focus event work?

Tags: events, browser, focus, xul

I have this browser element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <browser
        id="mybrowser"
        onclick="dump('CLICKED!\n')"
        onfocus="dump('FOCUSED!\n')"
        type="content"
        src="http://www.google.com/"
        flex="1" />

</window>
```

and the `onclick` is working well, but not the `onfocus`. Both are inherited from [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Event_Handlers), so it should work.

Any idea why it's not working?

**obs.** I know I can make it work by adding a focus listener to the window. But I want to know why the `onclick` is corrected inherited and working for the browser element, while the `onfocus` not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that click events bubble, but focus (and blur) events do not. (Load and unload events are slightly different in that an event handler on a page's [i]frame element will fire as if the event had bubbled. They still don't bubble to a `<browser type="content">`.)

I don't know a reference for why these events don't bubble.